# Hash function sending close keys in the same place

Tags: c, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I've seen that this question has already been asked but i didn't find suitable answer for my case.
I have some very long strings of letters in the alphabet {A, C, G, T} and want to hash them into an array with q slots. So far i'm good, the problem is I also need strings that differ for just one letter to be mapped to the same thing, for example Hash(ACTGTT) and Hash(ATTGTT) must have the same output. I've attributed to the letters the values {0, 1, 2, 3} respectively (feel free to change them at will) and tried some sums and multiplying for primes but it doesn't really work; any ideas? Here's where i was at so far (it's a bit more complicated but i think you get the point):

```
int fash(char r){
  if (r=='A') return 0;
  if (r=='C') return 1;
  if (r=='G') return 2;
  if (r=='T') return 3;
}

int hash(char kmero[], int p, int q, int k){
  int c=0;
  for (int u=0; u<k; u++)
    c=((c+ fash(kmero[u]))*p)% q; 
  return c;
}

int main(){
  char* kmero1={'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};
  char* kmero2={'A', 'T', 'G', 'T'};
  if (hash(kmero1, 5, 2, 4)==hash(kmero2, 5, 2, 4))
    return 1;
   else return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please show us your code, and a couple of examples of what you expect and what you actually get

Comment: Are all the strings of the same length?

Comment: The principles of [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) could possibly be useful.

Comment: Yes, all the strings have the same length

Comment: This looks promising

Comment: Still no clue though

Comment: `int c` `int p, int q, int k` `int u` - you will go way further if you use descriptive variable names. Ex. instead of `int k` you could use `int kmerolength`.

Comment: `I also need strings that differ for just one letter to be mapped to the same thing` - that basicaly means hash returns a constant.

Comment: A k-mere is a sequence of k letters in dna sequencing, so it kinda made sense. p is used for a bit of a long stoey and q is a prime that is not p

Comment: If all strings with one character difference have the same hash, then all strings that differ from one of those strings by one character must also have the same hash - and so on.  Your hash function becomes `return 0;`.

Comment: That is a good point, hehe

Comment: Though it's worth saying that not all sequences are present in input, for example if my strings were ATGTCT, AGGTCT and TTTTTT i could have different outputs

Comment: jasonharper is right, see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27465). The property of difference in only a single letter is "hamming distance of 1"

Comment: I think you want Nearest Neighbor search, try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041273/efficient-implementation-of-the-nearest-neighbour-search

Comment: If you are looking for near matches: [BK Trees](https://signal-to-noise.xyz/post/bk-tree/) are a data structure that can do a "fuzzy" search. You could use the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) as criterion, but it will be re-calculated for every node you traverse, so for very long strings this might not be feasible.